# XAMPP and hidden service MYSQL DB cant connect

Tags: mysql

I am trying to remotely connect to my hidden service MySQL DB

```
mysql -u root -p -h 127.0.0.1 connected
```

works fine on local host

I am following this tutorial on reddit:

```
/r/TOR/comments/222bum/running_mysql_as_a_hidden_service/
```

I have xampp running on Ubuntu and and tor MySQL listens to port 3306 and Apache on 80

I am trying to connect to my DB remotely with command:

```
proxychains mysql -u root  -p -h http://xxxxxxx.onion DBNAME
```

Getting this error:

> ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on
>   'http://xxxxxxxxx.onion' (111)

tried this with socat

```
socat TCP-LISTEN:3308 SOCKS4A:127.0.0.1:xxxxj.onion:3306,socksport=9050
```

or

```
socat TCP-LISTEN:3308 SOCKS4A:localhost:xxxxj.onion:3306,socksport=9050
```

did not work in tor panel it says but only when i try to  proxychains mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u user -p P 33606

> Sep 26 18:43:09.000 [warn] Rejecting SOCKS request for anonymous
>   connection to private address [scrubbed].

```
    thanks for reply but still cant get   it to work
root:/var/lib/tor/hidden_service$ proxychains mysql -u user -h TOR.onion database -p
ProxyChains-3.1 (http://proxychains.sf.net)
Enter password: 
|DNS-request| TOR.onion 
|S-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<><>-4.2.2.2:53-<><>-OK`enter code here`
|DNS-response| TOR.onion is 104.239.213.7
|S-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<><>-104.239.213.7:3306-<--timeout
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'TOR.onion' (111)
GRANT ALL ON Databasename.* TO 'user'@'127.0.0.1
getting some error in console phpmyadmin SQL error
```

i m prety new to this any help is appreicated

mysql workbench works fine on localhost but when trying to add the onion instead of localhost it dosent work:******
Any suggestions thanks

Comment: Running MySQL as a hidden Tor service is... unique. Kinda fascinating, to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

1. Change your interface to 0.0.0.0 so external connections can happen (`bind-address=0.0.0.0` in `my.cnf` or equivalent)
2. `GRANT` access to the **external** IP in MySQL: `GRANT ALL ON <DB>.* TO '<user>'@'<external_ip>';`